# Could not parse timeStamp <1.65269E+12> using format defined by property jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=ms on sample 1.65269E+12,3752

Tags: html, jmeter, report

At the time of generating the Html report getting below error.

please give the Suggestion to overcome this issue.

thanks in advance.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXmXE.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles), JMeter expects to find a [long](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_data_types.asp) value representing a [timestamp in milliseconds since beginning of Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

You should replace `1.65269E+12` with its "long" equivalent of `1652690000000`

If you opened and saved JMeter's .jtl results file using [Excel](https://office.live.com/start/excel.aspx) or equivalent you should re-save it again and configure the first column to contain numeric values [without floating points](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/available-number-formats-in-excel-0afe8f52-97db-41f1-b972-4b46e9f1e8d2).

Also be aware that you can [run a JMeter test and generate HTML reporting dashboard in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode/) in one shot like:

```
 jmeter -n -t /path/to/testplan.jmx -l /path/to/testresult.jtl -e -o /path/to/dashboard
```

More information: [Generating Reports](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report)